# C# "cannot assign field because it is a foreach iteration variable"

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to trim the column headers of a CSV file, fields below is an array that contains the header names, where would I place trim()? I've placed it with the foreach loop but VS tells me "cannot assign field because it is a foreach iteration variable". What am I doing wrong?

```
while ((fields = csv.GetCSVLine()) != null) 
{
    if (header)
    {
        foreach (string field in fields) 
        {
              //field = field.trim(); //VS: "cannot assign field because it is a foreach iteration variable"
          headers.Add(field);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it on the same line as the `Add()` call. No need to overwrite the variable `field` if you pass the result of `Trim()` directly to `Add()`.

```
foreach (string field in fields) 
{
    headers.Add(field.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to change the value of the item you're working on.

Just do

```
var trimmedField=field.Trim();
headers.Add(trimmedField);
```

Comment: Or to be more concise you could use headers.Add(field.Trim());

Comment: Equally sensible, especially if you only use the trimmed version once.

Answer (score 3):

```
    foreach (string field in fields) 
    {
      headers.Add(field.Trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the compiler has already told you exactly what you're doing wrong: You're trying to assign something that's an iteration variable, which you're evidently not allowed to do.

The other answers here have told you what you can do instead: either copy the iteration variable into another variable and trim that, or skip the assignment altogether and add the trimmed value directly.

Comment: To be fair, the compiler warning is really unhelpful about what you should be doing, and the MSDN docs really aren't spectacular either. But it all makes a certain sort of sense, once you start understanding how C# handles value and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Although the appearance would be less 'modern', its likely about as fast to execute and resource-friendly to simply utilize a **For** loop in the case described, i.e.:

```
while ((fields = csv.GetCSVLine()) != null) {
    if (header) {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < fields.Count; ii++) {
            headers.Add(field);
}   }   }
```

Of course I'm confident the issue was solved this years ago, but am just putting this out there to assist others browsing through.  I personally think it's a bit silly we're not allowed to assign values to foreach iterators (I suspect they could easily cover the *hurdle* (such as it is) at compile and / or run time).